# Предустановка типа данных dataframe pandas при помощи параметра dtype для увеличения скорости обработки

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, оптимизация, dataframe

закачиваю dataframe

```
file = 'expru1.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(file, 'Лист1', header=None, skiprows=4)
```

получаю такой df:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

c таким типом данных:

```
[5 rows x 14 columns]
0      object
1      object
2      object
3      object
4      object
5      object
6      object
7      object
8      object
9     float64
10    float64
11    float64
12    float64
13    float64
dtype: object
```

тут все понятно. НО, меня не устраивает время обработки - на excel файл размером в 245 000 строк уходит почти 2 минуты.

Теряется смысл использовать pandas c excel файлом, гораздо проще сохранять в txt и пользоваться обычным инструментарием python, так гораздо быстрее работает (5-7 сек)

С этими мыслями перешерстил интернет, понял что если заранее указать тип данных   используя параметр dtype, то закачка должна быть быстрее (тратиться меньше  ресурса на распознавание типа данных, как я понял).

Использую параметр dtype=str:

```
file = 'expru1.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(file, 'Лист1', header=None, skiprows=4, dtype=str)
```

получаю такой df:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

c таким типом данных:

```
[5 rows x 14 columns]
0     object
1     object
2     object
3     object
4     object
5     object
6     object
7     object
8     object
9     object
10    object
11    object
12    object
13    object
dtype: object
```

но 1 - время обработки не меняется; 2 - тип данных для некоторых столбцов не меняется и остается object, а для других меняется на object, хотя я ожидал увидеть str

**По итогу два вопроса:

1 как увеличить скорость обработки данных?

2 почему не меняется тип данных во всех столбцах на str?**

Answer (score 1):

1. Врядли вы сможете значительно ускорить чтение Excel. Лучше всего хранить данные в одном из бинарных форматов, которые сохраняют информацию о типах данных столбцов и, соответственно, не тратят время на парсинг и определение типов данных. Я предпочитаю работать с форматами `Parquet` и `HDF5`
2. Строковые типы данных в Pandas отображаются как `object`.